# linear transformation to simplify linear discriminant analysis

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, discriminant-analysis

In a lecture on Linear Discriminant Analysis, it was mentioned that data given as
$$
x|y=0 \sim N(\mu_0,\Sigma)\\
x|y=1 \sim N(\mu_1,\Sigma)
$$
can be trnsformed by means of a linear transformation $\tilde{x}=a+Ax$ so that
$$
\tilde{x}|y=0\sim N((\Delta/2)e_1,I)\\
\tilde{x}|y=1\sim N(-(\Delta/2)e_1,I)\\
$$
where $\Delta=\sqrt{(\mu_1-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_0)}$ and $e_1$ is the basis vector $(1,0,0..)$. I can't figure out the form of $a$ and $A$. Matching the transformed means I get $a=-1/2A(\mu_1-\mu_0)$ and then $a+A\mu_1=\Delta/2e_1$ implies the first row of $A$ is proportional to $\mu_1-\mu_0$ and the remaining rows orthogonal to it. But so that the transformed variances are $I$, it is also required that $A\Sigma^{1/2}$ be orhtonormal, which is where I'm stuck.

(This question was posted on math stackexchange yesterday but I deleted it and replaced it with this question when I found the transformation being used in a statistics journal [article](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/STK9200/h21/efron_jasa1975.pdf).)

Comment: Do it in three steps: use an eigenbasis of $\Sigma,$ recenter to the midpoint of the means, and then rotate the coordinates to make $e_1$ coincide with the direction towards $\mu_0.$  Alternatively (more direct but algebraically much more involved and less insightful) plug $a + Ax$ into the first set of conditions and solve for $(a,A)$ that achieve the second set of conditions.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, it's clear now